# Concatenating lists of lists in F#

Tags: list, f#

From pseudo C#, I have this:

```
class C
{
   List<A> a;
   List<B> b;
}

List<C> L;
```

I would like to get to get two lists: ListA and ListB where ListA is the concatenation of all 'a' fields from the list L, and similar for ListB.

it would be something like:

```
var ListA = new List<A>();
var ListB = new List<B>();
foreach (var l in L)
{
    ListA.Append(l.a);
    ListB.Append(l.b);
}
```

In F#,
I assume it would be something like: `let ListA = L |> List.Concat` (but how do I say to pick the field `a`?)

or could it be done as a `let ListA = L |> List.Fold (fun acc value -> acc.Concat value)` (how do I specify the empty list here?)

or, can it be done like this?

```
let getElementsA (l : C list) =
    seq {
        for element in l do
            for a in element.a do
                yield a
    }
```

but isn't that too verbose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `List.collect`, or `Seq.collect` for C# lists, is for:

```ml
let listA = l |> Seq.collect (fun element -> element.a) |> List.ofSeq
let listB = l |> Seq.collect (fun element -> element.b) |> List.ofSeq
```

Or if you really need to do it in one iteration you can use a fold:

```ml
let (seqA, seqB) =
  l |> Seq.fold
         (fun (seqA, seqB) element -> (Seq.append element.a seqA, Seq.append element.b seqB))
         ([], [])
```

Comment: Since my lists come from a C# module, the concatenated list is Generic.List<A>, how can I convert it to a F# 'A list'?

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed `a` and `b` are lists. In that case `List.collect` and the `@` operator should be used instead of `List.map` and `::`

Comment: just tried:         let a = (entries |> List.collect (fun e -> e.a)) but it doesn't compile: it says that the expression was expected to have the list type but has the Generic.List type

Comment: Oh, of course, the inner lists are C# lists too. Then `entries |> Seq.collect (fun e -> e.a) |> List.ofSeq` should work better I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `List.collect`:

```
let getElementsA (cs : C list) = cs |> List.collect (fun c -> c.a)
```

if the property type is `System.Collection.List<T>` then you can use `Seq.collect`:

```
let getElementsA (cs : C list) = cs |> Seq.collect (fun c -> c.AS)
```

this returns a `A seq` which you can convert into a list using `List.ofSeq`:

```
let getElementsA (cs : C list) = cs |> Seq.collect (fun c -> c.AS) |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: thanks, I'll look in to the collect method; I haven't seen this one yet (F# day 4 or 5 now :))

Answer (score 1):

F# uses other lists, function objects (like delegates). You can find all that you need in `Microsoft.FSharp` namespace

---

If I have this code in F#.
A function that resives a list with action and return nothing (`list:'a list -> action:('a -> unit) -> unit`).

```ml
module FS =
    let actLit list action =
        list
        |> List.iter (action)
```

For this on C#, include `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule` module and call functions work with F# lists. `ListModule.OfSeq(l)` creates new F# list.

`Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FunctionModule` contains conversion methods.

After converting you can call it.

```
var a = new List<int> ();
var list = ListModule.OfSeq(a);
var func = FuncConvert.FromAction<int>(Console.WriteLine);

FS.actLit(list, func);
```